# Bound first order derivative by $L^2$ norm of elliptic elliptic operator

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces, regularity-theory-of-pdes

Consider an symmetric 2nd order differential operator on a bounded domain with smooth boundary $$A=-\sum_{i,j=1}^n \partial_j (a^{ij}(x)\partial_i)$$ be uniformly elliptic if there exists $C_0>0$ such that $\sum_{i,j=1}^n a^{ij}(x)\xi_i\xi_j \ge C_0\sum_{i=1}^n \xi_i^2$. I aim to show the following interpolation inequality: for all  $\epsilon>0$, there exists $C(\epsilon)>0$ such that $$\|\partial_i u\|_{0}\le \epsilon \|Au\|_{0}+C(\epsilon)\|u\|_{0},\quad \forall u\in H^2(\Omega)\cap H^1_0(\Omega).$$

Here $\|\cdot\|_0$ denotes the $L^2$ norm and we assume $a^{ij}\in C^1(\bar{\Omega})$.

---

I know the inequality holds for $A$ be Laplacian, since we know 
for all  $\epsilon>0$, there exists $C(\epsilon)>0$ such that $$\|\partial_i u\|_{0}\le \epsilon \|\partial_{ii} u\|_{0}+\dfrac{C}{\epsilon}\|u\|_{0},\quad \forall u\in H^2(\Omega)\cap H^1_0(\Omega),$$
but I don't know how to use the uniform ellipticity to get the desired result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $u \in H^2 \cap H^1_0$.  According to ellipticity we know that 
$$
C_0 \|\nabla u \|_{L^2}^2 =  \int_\Omega C_0 \partial_i u \partial_i u \le \int_\Omega a^{ij} \partial_i u \partial_j u.
$$
Next we integrate by parts, using the fact that $u=0$ on $\partial \Omega$:
$$
\int_\Omega a^{ij} \partial_i u \partial_j u = \int_\Omega -\partial_j(a^{ij} \partial_i u) u + \int_{\partial \Omega} a^{ij} \partial_i u u n_j = \int_\Omega -\partial_j(a^{ij} \partial_i u) u.
$$
Combining these and using Cauchy's inequality we find that 
$$
\|\nabla u\|^2_{L^2} \le \frac{1}{C_0} \int_\Omega Au \cdot u \le \int_\Omega \varepsilon |A u|^2 + \frac{1}{4 \varepsilon^2 C_0^2}|u|^2 = \varepsilon^2 \|A u\|_{L^2}^2 + \frac{1}{4\varepsilon^2 C_0^2} \|u\|_{L^2}^2.
$$
Upon taking square roots and using the trivial inequality $\sqrt{x^2 +y^2} \le |x|+ |y|$ we find that 
$$
\|\nabla u\|_{L^2} \le \varepsilon \|A u\|_{L^2} + \frac{1}{2\varepsilon C_0} \|u\|_{L^2},
$$
which is the desired inequality.